# How can I make an animation when using RevolutionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, animation, rotation

Let `ABCD` be a square with `AB=2`. Rotate the filled `ABD` (see picture) about `AB`.
[image]

I tried

```
RevolutionPlot3D[1 - Sqrt[1 - t^2], {t, 0, 1}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

and

```
RevolutionPlot3D[1  +  Sqrt[-3 + 4 t - t^2], {t, 1, 2}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

I tried with `Piecewise`

```
pw[u_] := 
 Piecewise[{{{u, 1 - Sqrt[1 - u^2]}, 
    0 <= u <= 1}, {{u, 1  +  Sqrt[-3 + 4 u - u^2]}, 1 < u <= 2}}]

RevolutionPlot3D[{pw[u][[1]], pw[u][[2]]}, {u, 0, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

How can I make an animation when using `RevolutionPlot3D`?

PS. Where is wrong when I use this?

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 Piecewise[{{1 - Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
    0 <= x <= 1}, {1  +  Sqrt[-3 + 4  x - x^2], 1 <= x < 2}}], {x, 0, 
  2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: You mean something like `Animate[RevolutionPlot3D[1 + Sqrt[-3 + 4  t - t^2], {t, 0, tmax}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {tmax,
   2, 4, .01}]`  ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I want to make `Animate` with the function `Piecewise`.

Comment: How about `Animate[RevolutionPlot3D[{pw[u][[1]], pw[u][[2]]}, {u, 0, tmax}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {tmax,
   1, 3, .01}]`  using the definition of your `pw. You can play with options to improve display as needed

Comment: @Nasser Thank you. Please see my edit.

Comment: `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**

- animate
- axis is the rotation axis, we can set `axis={0,0,1}` or `axis={1,0,0}` etc.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1 - Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
     0 <= x <= 1}, {1 + Sqrt[-3 + 4      x - x^2], 1 <= x < 2}}];
plot = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Exclusions -> None, Filling -> Top];
reg = RotationTransform[π/2, {1, 0, 0}]@
   RegionProduct[DiscretizeGraphics[plot], Point[{0.}]];
draw[t_, axis_ : {0, 0, 1}] := 
 Module[{plot1, plot2, reg2}, 
  plot1 = RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, {θ, 0, t}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, 
    RevolutionAxis -> axis, Exclusions -> None, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  plot2 = 
   RevolutionPlot3D[2, {x, 0, 2}, {θ, 0, t}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, 
    RevolutionAxis -> axis, Exclusions -> None, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  plot = 
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None,
     Filling -> Top];
  reg2 = RotationTransform[t, axis]@reg;
  Show[plot1, plot2, Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], reg}], 
   Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], reg2}], PlotRange -> 2, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium]]
ani = Manipulate[
  GraphicsRow@{draw[t, {0, 0, 1}], 
    draw[t, {1, 0, 0}]}, {t, $MachineEpsilon, 2    π}]
```

[image]

**Original**

- Since the original seems want to rotation a filled region, here we draw a revolution solid.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]; 
pw[u_] := 
 Piecewise[{{{u, 1 - Sqrt[1 - u^2]}, 
    0 <= u <= 1}, {{u, 1 + Sqrt[-3 + 4  u - u^2]}, 1 < u <= 2}}]
plot = ParametricPlot[pw[u], {u, 0, 2}, Exclusions -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];
pts = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, -1][[1]];
poly2d = Join[pts, {{0, pts[[-1]] // Last}}] // Polygon;
poly3d = RegionProduct[poly2d, Point[{0}]];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[poly3d];
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
   2 π]
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.1}];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan], EdgeForm[]], 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ViewPoint -> Right, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I rotate `ox` axis?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure now why

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 Piecewise[{{1 - Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
    0 <= x <= 1}, {1  +  Sqrt[-3 + 4  x - x^2], 1 <= x < 2}}], {x, 0, 
  2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

gives

[image]

Until someone finds out, here is a simple workaround

```
p[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[
   {{1 - Sqrt[1 - x^2], 0 <= x < 1},
    {1 + Sqrt[-3 + 4   x - x^2], 1 <= x < 2}
    }
   ];
RevolutionPlot3D[
 p[x], {x, 0, 2},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 Mesh -> None,
 RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

To animate

```
p[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[{{1 - Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
     0 <= x < 1}, {1 + Sqrt[-3 + 4    x - x^2], 1 <= x < 2}}];
Animate[
 RevolutionPlot3D[p[x], {x, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-1, 2}}], {tmax, 1, 4, .01}]
```

[image]